# pytorch to Onnx(OCR model)

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, ocr, onnx

I am trying to convert pytorch model in the given repo https://github.com/clovaai/deep-text-recognition-benchmark
to onnx.

I am facing the issue while doing so.

```
Failed to export an ONNX attribute 'onnx::Gather', since it's not constant, please try to make things (e.g., kernel size) static if possible
```

Link to the git issue https://github.com/clovaai/deep-text-recognition-benchmark/issues/76

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adaptive_avg_pool2d  is not supported in my case and this  nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((None,1)) also have have issue.

Answer (score 1):

The layer

`nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((None,1))` .

None is actually causing the error; we need to make it static to solve the error. you can change 'None' to a static value. For example:

`nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((512,1))`.